# Wpf привязка свойств

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, анимация, binding

Есть 2 контрола A типа ControlA и B типа ControlB. В каждом из них я определил свойство зависимости HighlightedProperty типа bool. В стилях по наведению мыши я изменяю это свойство, а по изменению этого свойства меняю цвет фона контрола:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ControlA}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundControlA}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Highlighted" Value="True"/>
            </Trigger>

            <Trigger Property="Highlighted" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HighlightedColor}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Я хочу что бы при наведении как на контролА, так и на контролБ выделялись оба контрола, поэтому создаю привязки (создаю в коде, потому что бы контролы будут добавляться и удаляться динамически), но они не работают как должны:

```
Binding bindingA = new Binding("Highlighted");
bindingA.Source = controlA;
controlB.SetBinding(ControlB.HighlightedProperty, bindingA);

Binding bindingB = new Binding("Highlighted");
bindingB.Source = controlB;
controlA.SetBinding(ControlA.HighlightedProperty, bindingB);
```

Если оставить обе привязки, то ни один из контролов не будет менять цвет, если убрать одну из них, то только один контрол будет менять цвет при наведении мышью на другой. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: А можно немного пояснений, что за ControlA и ControlB? Вот хоть убейте, уже мин 20 гуглю о таком чудо свойстве, как `Highlighted`.

Comment: controlA и controlB - это контролы, наследованные от UserControl. Highlighted - это определенной мной свойство зависимости.      public partial class ControlA : UserControl
    {
        public ControlA()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HighlightedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Highlighted", typeof(bool), typeof(ControlA));
        public bool Highlighted
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(HighlightedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HighlightedProperty, value); }
        }
    }

Comment: А режим привязки какой по умолчанию у свойства Highlighted?

Comment: Спасибо за вопрос, очень интересный!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина такого поведения стандартна: в WPF есть строгий порядок определения значения свойства зависимости, при этом явная установка значения имеет самый высокий приоритет. Когда вы пишете `controlA.SetBinding(ControlA.HighlightedProperty, bindingB)` — это тоже самое, что если бы вы написали в разметке `Highlighted="{Binding ...}"`, т. е. та самая явная установка свойства. Для того, чтобы на свойство действовали триггеры *из стиля*, установка значения свойства должна быть *тоже внутри стиля*, т. е. в разметке вместо `Highlighted="{Binding ...}"` надо писать `<Setter Property="Highlighted" Value="{Binding ...}"/>` в стиле. В коде это могло бы выглядеть как-то так:

```
// Стиль заморожен, придется создавать новый
var style = new Style(typeof(СontrolA), controlA.Style);
var setter = new Setter(ControlA.HighlightedProperty, new Binding(...));
style.Setters.Add(setter);
controlA.Style = style;
```

Но когда вы это сделаете, вы столкнетесь еще с одной проблемой — после первого наведения цвет фона поменяется и назад уже не вернется, т. к. привязка будет в приоритете перед триггером.

Выход есть и он — отказаться от привязки вообще, действовать *только через триггеры*, т. е. нужно во второй контрол добавить триггер на изменение `IsMouseOver` первого и наоборот (тут вы поймете, что дополнительное свойство `Highlighted` вам не нужно вовсе):

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HighlightedColor}"/>
    </Trigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=controlB, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HighlightedColor}"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Или, в коде:

```
var style = new Style(typeof(ControlA), controlA.Style);
var setter = new Setter(BackgroundProperty, Resources["HighlightedColor"]);
var dataTrigger = new DataTrigger
{
    Binding = new Binding("IsMouseOver") { Source = controlB },
    Value = true,
    Setters = { setter }
};
style.Triggers.Add(dataTrigger);
ControlA.Style = style;
```

Comment: Спасибо! Свойство Highlighted было добавлено, на будущее, потому что планируется различное поведение - при наведении мышью на элементе, при клике по ним, при изменении каких-то внутренних свойств и тд. Правда из-за того, что объекты создаются динамически и из-за наличия большого количества триггеров, меняющих внешний вид получится довольно много кода.. И еще больше, что бы заменить изменение фона анимацией.